# Publishing apk through unity : StreamingAssets folder is not present in phone after installation

Tags: unity-game-engine, directory, apk, streaming, assets

I have published an apk from unity.

At the start the application needs to

1. read some config params, from a local json file(in streaming assets folder)
2. load some images from  (streaming assets folder)

In the subsequent screens app needs to read json from api call.

The application works as intended in unity editor but does not work after apk installation. The StreamingAssets folder is not present in phone after installation.

I have published an apk from unity.

There are some resources fetched from web via api calls (i.e. http request)

Also, there are some config parameters to be fetched from local json file (placed inside streaming assets)

The application works fine in unity editor.

After installing apk, the json file(in streaming assets folder) is not getting fetched. Hence not able to read config params.

However the api calls are still working fine in apk. I an able to load remote images from http requests

After installing apk, I have checked inside "Android\obb\com.ProjectName" folder, there is no "streaming assets" folder in it.

Am I missing anything in project settings or build settings?

Thank You! for going through this post.

Comment: No, but you forgot to read the manual I guess https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html, there's no such folder on Android.

Comment: Shingo,  Thank You for your reply. 

I missed the "UnityWebRequest" thing for accessing streaming Asset files. It working fine now.